# Passing Function Pointer - What am I doing Wrong?

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following function to link a button on a ui file with a function within the class.

```
void Window::connectButton() {
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(clear()));
}
```

What I actually want to achieve is to link the button with a function in a derived class. I can't reuse the `connect()` function above because I cannot access `ui->pushButton` from the derived class. 
So what I ended up with was this:

```
void Window::connectButton(void (*func)(void)) {
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(func()));
}
```

In case it's useful, this function is implemented in the derived class as:

```
void Transmit::setWindow() {
    windowTitle();
    setWindowSize();

    connectButton(clear);
    //clear is a redefined function for the derived class
    //inherited from the Window class
}
```

I keep on getting the issue saying that `func` is not used in the `connectButton(void (*)())` function and that `func2` cannot be passed into `connectButton(void (*)())`.

This is my first experiment with function pointers so can anyone point me in the direction of my mistakes or, if more viable, a better way of implementing the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the error message. What is `func2`?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that `func2` is a non-static member function.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to forgive me, I'm new to forums.

Comment: What is a minimal reproducible example? func2 is actually a redefinition of function1 in the derived class. I will edit the post.

Comment: A [mre] is explained by this link. Just click on the link, and read it. Basically, anyone in the world should be able to copy/paste the code, ***exactly as shown***, and reproduce your problem. Otherwise, by definition, it's not ***reproducible***. And it must be only the bare ***minimum*** required to reproduce your problem, and not an entire code dump. But that's besides the point, it's obvious that "clear" is not a function, it is a class method. Class methods cannot be converted to function pointers. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Apologies, yes, clear is non-static. I have tried declaring it static but it caused problems because it changes the private variables:

Comment: Well, only a static function can be converted to a function pointer. A non-static function cannot, because it is not really a function but a class method. This is the only way that C++ works, and there is no workaround.

Comment: Sorry, keep pressing enter. `void Transmit::clear() {
    x.clear();
    y.clear();
    x_temp.clear();
    y_temp.clear();

    update();
}` x, y, x_temp and y_temp are private variables of the class.

Comment: @Brandy -- Another way to explain why this cannot work is for the simple fact that to call a non-static member function, you need an instance of an object to make the call to fulfill the syntax.  Look at the syntax of calling a non-static member function using a pointer: `(object->*func)()` or `(object.*func)()`.  So where will "qt" get the `object` part of that syntax from?  On the other hand, a "normal" function pointer requires only `func()` or `(*func)()` to make the callback work.

Answer (score 2):

To connect a signal with a function, you need to use the ["New" Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

```
void Window::connectButton(void (*func)(void)) {
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::released, func);
}
```

If you want to connect to member functions, then you can use lambdas. The easiest way to support that is by using `std::function`

```
void Window::connectButton(std::function<void()> func) {
    connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::released, func);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what `func2` is, but the more immediate problem is that Qt's `SLOT()` macro is not actually working with function pointers at all, but it's really taking `func()` as a char constant.

Easiest way out will be to move the `SLOT()`-macro to the calling function, i.e.:

```
void Window::connectButton(const char* method) {
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, method);
}

void Transmit::setWindow() {
    connectButton(SLOT(clear()));
}
```

The above is assuming that `this` in `Window::connectButton()` actually refers to the object that you want to call `clear()` on. Otherwise, you'd use:

```
void Window::connectButton(QObject* receiver, const char* method) {
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(released()), receiver, method);
}

void Transmit::setWindow() {
    connectButton(myobject, SLOT(clear()));
}
```

Comment: well, that will only work if `method` is actaully amethod from `this`

Comment: As far as I understand the question, that is the case, here (`clear()` being a member of `Transmit` and `Transmit` being a derived class of `Window`). But otherwise, you'd simply pass the corresponding `QObject*` as an additional parameter, and use it in place of `this` in the `connect()`-call.

Comment: why not add that to your answer

Comment: True. Done that.